# Tracking changes in Django with PostgreSQL

Tags: django, database, postgresql

I have a Django project with PostgreSQL as database.

- There are few tables that describe state (let's call them "state tables")
- There are several servers that can modify state (Each one modifies its own table)
- There is few servers that read the state (let's call them "readers") and modifies internal stuff based on current state of the tables.

What I'd like to do is to give the readers ability to know what row in state tables was changed, so that it won't have to scan all the tables all the time.

Currently I have a special tracking table and a post_save() trigger on all state tables. The post_save trigger saves the table name and the ID.
Initially the plan was to define sequence ID on the tracking table and to check whether "last known tracking ID" is the largest. If it's not - I would scan all of the tracked entries and know what states were changed.

However, it seems that PostgreSQL's indexes are not promised to be sequential. I don't mind the gaps between them, but I do rely on tracking record N+1 to have ID bigger than record N.

Any advice?

Comment: maybe add another table and every time you change something, mention it there. for example id=x in table=x is changed. now your reader checks this table first for changes and find the data by the id and table id you provided there and after changes has been made or whatever you trying to do, delete the change record on the table. surely this way it will be faster but to know how much you should test it yourself. and let me know the result if you did. Good Luck

Comment: Oh, just added to the post: there are several readers, so I can't just delete an entry (otherwise another one wouldn't see it)

Comment: do all of them need to do some stuff for each change? or ...? in general you can add a status for each reader. like a BooleanField for each reader (reader 1, reader 2 and etc) and instead of deleting the change row just set the reader status to 1 which means this reader already done its job. and delete the change if all other readers done their job which means all the BooleanFields are 1 so you have less rows and more speed. @Vasisualiy

Comment: Yes, I need all of them to do all.. This solution might work but it means changing models whenever new reader is added, which is something I'd like to avoid

Comment: Okay, what about this: lets say you have 5 readers for now. instead of using a boolean field for each reader just use an integer field and every time a reader done its job successfully add one to this number. and if your final number is 5 it means that all of your readers done their job and you can delete the entry. and every time you add a reader you just need to change a number in your code. bad thing is you can't know which readers are done but i don't know if you need that or not. you can also save logs for each readers so you access their status for every work.